# How to escape double image loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my web project, I have a different html pages and the _Layout page.
This layout page displays the profile photo of a user like this:

```
 <img src="~/Path/avatar.png" id="avatar">
```

And I implemented one thing: if the user haven't ever uploaded the profile photo, _Layout page will always display the standard `avatar.png`. Else, if he uploaded their avatar, I do next:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Account/HasAvatar/',
        success:
            function (data) { //data - it's the name of the image file
                console.log(data);
                if (data == null)
                    return;
            $("#avatar").attr("src", window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+"/Path/" + data);
        }
    })
```

If the current user has already uploaded the profile photo, controller method `HasAvatar()` returns its name and then jquery changes the standard `<img src="">` to an already existed image. But here I have a problem. When a user load any page, firstly he can see the standard avatar and only then (in 0.2 sec) the current user's image is loaded. How to escape this double image loading? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css to hide the img initially e.g. using `style="display:none;"` and then when the image loads, display it again like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Account/HasAvatar/',
    success:
        function (data) { //data - it's the name of the image file
            console.log(data);
            if (data == null){
                $("#avatar").css('display', 'initial');
                return;
            }
            $("#avatar").one('load', function(){
                $("#avatar").css('display', 'initial');
            });
            $("#avatar").attr("src", window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+"/Path/" + data);
        }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i'm asked for!

Comment: Do note, that some older browsers may still load the placeholder avatar (although it wont show it). Most new browsers though, will most likely use the `display: none;` to determine that the image should not be loaded initially.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the image exists server side and replace the src before you even send it to the client.

Comment: You mean put this image element inside the div, and then append this element with already created <img src=""?